# gnome installed, but gives segmentation fault every time

Tags: gnome

I've installed gnome through Ubuntu Software Center but when I choose it from the login menu and login then there is only my desktop background, when I try running it from the terminal I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried installing it from terminal and no result.

my graphic card is nvidia 330m and I also tried removing the xorg config file and removing all the gnome config files and no result.

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in what you have done when you say you have removed config files?

Comment: I ran this: rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*

Comment: Can you add any useful information from ~/.xsession-errors and /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: Xorg.0.log doesn't seem to care at all!
here is my xsession errors [link](http://pastebin.com/RXPn4pMm) the only thing notable is opengl fatal errors!